# Print XQuery Info through java api in Basex

Tags: java, basex

I want to print QueryInfo after executing XQuery in BaseX.

Following is my XQuery

```
declare namespace db ='http://basex.org/modules/db'; 
declare option db:queryinfo 'true'; 
for $i in 1 to 1 return db:open('testDB')/*
```

How can my program print the QueryInfo?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BaseXClient.Query.info()` function. A [complete example can be found in the BaseX Github repository](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-examples/src/main/java/org/basex/examples/api/QueryExample.java), here I stripped it down to the most relevant lines:

```
  final BaseXClient session = new BaseXClient("localhost", 1984, "admin", "admin");
  final String input = "(: your query :)";
  final BaseXClient.Query query = session.query(input);
  System.out.println(query.info());
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it; read more in the [FAQ].